# VBA Copy Paste based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet that has two different drop down variables with 3-4 options in the drop down each. I.E First drop down has the option to be {2-Tier, 3-Tier, 4-Tier, 40-Tier} and the second can be {2-Tier, 3-Tier, 4-Tier}. I'm very new to VBA, and have only ever worked with SQL before, so I'm kind of shooting in the dark here.

Basically, based on the drop down selected, I would like the spreadsheet to "copy and paste" a pricing grid from another corresponding other tab, and paste it on a "set up sheet". Since there are two drop downs, I imagine Columns 8-16 being used for the first pricing grid and then 18 down being used for the second set of pricing grids.

Here's what I kind of have so far:

```
     Sub Ifs()
    If Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B3) = "2-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("2 Tier MEC Rates").Range(A1, F3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A7)

ElseIf If Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B3) = "3-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("3 Tier MEC Rates").Range(A1, F4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A7)

ElseIf If Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B3) = "4-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("4 Tier MEC Rates").Range(A1, F5).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A7)

ElseIf If Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B3) = "40-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("7 Tier MEC Rates").Range(A1, F8).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A7)

    End If

If Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B4) = "2-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("2 Tier LM Rates").Range(A2, E12).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A18)

ElseIf Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B4) = "3-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("3 Tier LM Rates").Range(A2, E15).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A18)

ElseIf Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(B4) = "4-Tier" Then
    Worksheets("4 Tier LM Rates").Range(A2, E18).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Set Up Table").Range(A18)

End If

End Sub
```

My only other fear here is that [other than I'm totally doing this wrong], is that all my pricing tables have formulas based on other variables to determine the correct pricing, and that will somehow get messed up in all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would take a look at utilising `select ... case` which you can learn about here:
[Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

This will tidy up your many many `if` statements and make it much easier for you to decide what happens "if" a particular option has been selected.